# Permissions to access Facebook API Pages node for app in development mode

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions

I am developing an app and I need to get data from the Facebook API at the Pages node. I will only get data from Publicly available pages. Since last year, Facebook requires app review when this goes public, but to my understanding no review should be required when the app is in development mode (like the one I am developing). I have searched Stackoverflow but all the answers date back to before the new rules were implemented by Facebook (after the scandal last year). Does anyone know if it is possible to access the Facebook API at the Pages node without undergoing the app review? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> no review should be required when the app is in development mode

That applies mostly to usage of un-reviewed permissions.

The [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS) feature however requires review in any case. (If it didn’t, anyone could use it to still grab data from public pages without any oversight, by simply leaving their apps in dev mode.)

---

To develop your app, you will need to request `manage_pages` permission and test with pages your app user is an admin of. Only after review will you be able to access content of public pages.